# Trying to extend class with inheritance, but keep getting errors

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a product. I am using a previous class, as the only difference between prior and now, is that there is the option of a 10% discount (float 0.1) which can be multiplied by the price, if the order quantity exceeds 10 units.

I extended the Product class using DisountedProduct as the inherited class, but when I call the constructor from the parent class, I get the error "Invalid method declaration, return type required."

I have read the java explanation of inheritance but It doesn't mention this.

Please help

```
public class DiscountedProduct extends Product {

private float discount;
private String name;
private double price;
private int quantity;

public Product(String name, double price, int quantity){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

//Get//

public float getDiscount(){
    return discount;
}

//Set//

public void setDiscount(float value){
    this.discount = value;
}
}


    public class Product {

private String name;
private double price;
private int quantity;

public Product(String name, double price, int quantity){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

//Get Methods//

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}

public double getTotalPrice(){
    return quantity * price;
}

//Set Methods//
public void setName(String value){
    this.name = value;
}

public void setPrice(double value){
    this.price = value;
}

public void setQuantity(int value){
    this.quantity = value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `DiscountedProduct`, replace

```
public Product(String name, double price, int quantity)
```

with

```
public DiscountedProduct(String name, double price, int quantity)
```

You have the constructor for the wrong class

Also, you don't need to set all the variables in your `DiscountedProduct` constructor, just call the super constructor; replace the entire method with

```
public DiscountedProduct(String name, double price, int quantity) {
    super(name, price, quantity);

}
```

Comment: Fixed, got confused with c#

Comment: Thanks guys. massive help

Answer (score 0):

The constructor in the `DiscountedProduct` class should be `DiscountedProduct` instead of `Product`.

Also, `DiscountedProduct` should not define the fields already defined in the parent, and constructor should call `super(name, price, quantity)` instead of initializing the fields itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your Product class is set up fine - the problem seems to be in the constructor for your DiscountedProduct class. The constructor for the DiscountedProduct class should have the same name as the class name: DiscountedProduct. Additionally, the object parameters like `name` and `price` are already defined by the parent class, Product. The `super()` method invokes the Product class constructor. You need to call the `super()` method and pass it the values used to instantiate a DiscountedProduct.

```
public DiscountedProduct(String name, double price, int quantity){
    super(name, price, quantity);
}
```

The fixed constructor should look like the above block. Had no problems with it on my machine.

If you wanted the DiscountedProduct to have a parameter that its parent class does not have, you would define it in its constructor and pass in the corresponding argument, like so:

```
public DiscountedProduct(String name, double price, int quantity, float defaultDiscount){
        super(name, price, quantity);
        this.discount = defaultDiscount;
    }
```